# error C# type is used as a field

Tags: c#

hi im getting some weird errors

http://pastebin.com/edBdmFAV is the sourcecode

i try adding an object to to main

```
    ConsoleRectangle b = new ConsoleRectangle(10, 10, 10, 10, ConsoleColor.White);
    b.Draw();
```

doesnt work, errors are in main and not in clas.

Error   1   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Error   2   'TestTest.Program.b' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: there's no `b.Draw();` in the pastebin code you linked. Could you post the code that gives the error?

Answer (score 1):

The statement `b.Draw()` can only be made *inside* a method (or property).

It is currently *outside* of any method.

Comment: i'm a beginner in C# so outside of any method means? i cant draw it?

Comment: @user2058794 post the full code. If the error is in a method paste the method. So for example it should be : `public static void Main(string[] args){ ConsoleRectangle b = new ConsoleRectangle(10,10,10,10,ConsoleColor.White); b.Draw(); }`

Comment: @user2058794 - Methods are really basic constructs of types in .NET - if you don't understand what I mean, you should be reading a book.

Comment: @user2058794 where is your `Main()` method?

Comment: @user2058794 - How can that be the full source if it doesn't contain the two lines in the question?

Comment: @Aniket you did right but the console window should not crash, it was correct what you did, thanks! so tell me how i can make the console window still be there:

namespace TestTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { ConsoleRectangle b = new ConsoleRectangle(10, 10, 10, 10, ConsoleColor.White); b.Draw(); }
        
    }
}

Comment: You put the `Console.ReadKey();` call at the end to enable a wait

Comment: @Oded As I said, I'm a beginner, encountering OOP first time I'm not that good. I'm reading the book and it's difficult to learn something that is hard to learn. But Aniket solve my problem but the thing is that the console crashes, it should stay!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your great solution. Now I can finally enjoy my rectangle :> hehe

Comment: And if I want to change the background color of the console application, in what way can I fix it? Could I just add another line of private and color and such?

Comment: @Aniket I know now about ReadKey, thanks. Now I've a second question: "I want to change console application background color to something and the space should be in a different color, the string"

Comment: @user2058794 - Please stop asking follow on questions in comments to an answer. If you have additional questions, please ask new questions and refer to where they follow on from. Of course, _search first_ to find out if the new question has already been asked here before, in a different form.